# Join SQL query that has single id/row in 1 table, but links to multiple rows(same id) in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

First sorry for the long question title.

My question/situation is as such.

1.) I have 2 tables in mysql

2.) In first table, each listing has a unique id(each listing is in 1 row)

3.) In the second table it has the name/tags for images linked to the listing id,from the first table

4.) Each listing can have multiple images(multiple row in the second table).

What i am trying to do is to pull all the listings from table 1 and then use the listing.id from table one to pull all the rows of images from table 2 that are linked to the listing.id.
I am confused at the moment because there are multiple rows that has the same listing.id from table 2. ANd i tried query to display* but it only echo the last image(row) from table 2.

It doesnt seem to work when i join the 2 tables. And i am not sure if i query it twice then push array together.

Thanks for your time

```
 $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Listing JOIN listingpic ON 
    (Listing.id = listingpic.listingid)

 WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+300 DAY GROUP BY Listing.id ORDER BY Listing.id DESC") or die( mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
  $output[] = $row;
        }
        if (!empty($output)){

        echo json_encode( $output );}
        else{

            echo json_encode( [] );
        }
```

Comment: Did you iterate through the results with a `while($pictures = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {` ?

Comment: Yup i did, sorry just edited my question to show that.

Comment: Because if i use the group by listing.id, then it removes all the other pictures, and if i dont use the group by then it echo the listing.id once with every single picture.

Comment: Debug it with counting the rows. If it returns 1, then we know there is something wrong with the query. If not, then there seems to be something wrong with the output.

Comment: you are using group by in your where clause of your sql statement, this causes all of the responses corresponding to that listing to be grouped into one record, causing the behavior you are seeing

Comment: Ben, I think you need to remove the group by clause. I didn't notice it was in the query above until @theDarse mentioned it.

Comment: I have this Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/clarkho/public_html/App/testpic.php on line 21

Comment: theDarse, yer i am, but i am not sure how to group the pictures to 1 id. At the moment i am grouping by id, so there is only 1 pic show up because i only allow 1 row for the id. But i am not sure how do i still only allow 1 id but with multiple pictures.

Comment: Follow what @Felk said in the answer. As for your issue with the allocation size, it means the image is too big to store in PHP. You can increase the size in `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one result per id, because you used `GROUP BY Listing.id`. If you do not group them, you get one result row for each table 2 row, including the Listing id each time.

If you wish to retrieve the data in one query in the form "one id: multiple data", you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for example and then `explode()` the retrieved string result.

Otherwise get all ids from table 1 and then iterate over them in PHP and do one additional query per ID

Comment: I am not sure on how to use GROUP_CONCAT i tried to do GROUP_CONCAT(Listing.id)  after the join, but it is giving me syntax error.

Comment: You'd use the GROUP_CONCAT on a column of your second table. this would return a string representing all its rows concatenated

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: Don't use the viciously confusing MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *`, especially when you're joining tables. Instead, enumerate the columns you want in your result set.

Inherent to SQL is the idea that resultsets, like tables, are rectangular. They have rows and columns. Each row usually represents some real world item -- an "entity" -- and each column represents some attribute of that entity.

The result set you describe will, inherently, repeat information from your first table so it can show the info from the second table row by row.

What you want for a query is this, I think.

```
SELECT Listing.id, listing.date, 
       listingpic.id, listingpic.url, listingpic.caption
  FROM Listing
  JOIN listingpic ON  Listing.id = listingpic.listingid
  WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+300 DAY 
  ORDER BY Listing.id DESC, listingpic.id
```

This will give you one row per image.

If you're running out of memory it's because your result set is massive. You may want to limit it somehow, either using a first and last publication date:

```
  WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+300 DAY 
    AND date <  curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+293 DAY
```

or with a LIMIT clause.

```
  ORDER BY Listing.id DESC, listingpic.id
  LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Then do i use Group_concat to limit the listing.id to 1? So it will be 1 listing.id to Multiple pic.id?